# Windows folder organized similarly than desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, icons

As far as I understand, the Windows desktop is just a folder in the computer. However, it has a special organization compared to normal folders (when you turn on the computer, not when you access to it with the C:\Users*Name*\Desktop path where it looks like a regular folder):

- It does not extend beyond the screen, with a scroll bar, when there are too much icons to display
- The icons are organized as a table. However, contrary to normal folders with "large icons" display, the table is not filled horizontally from left to right. It is possible to put icons in each corner, or in the center, or any suitable organization.

This is the last feature I would like to obtain for a regular folder. Is it a way to achieve this goal, namely displaying icons everywhere I want on the screen?

PS: I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly what you want.  In order to accomplish your goal, you need to disable *auto arrange* and thus enable *free sorting*.

Full instructions are detailed here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/92758-windows-explorer-auto-arrange-disable.html

Have fun!