# (Windows 10) Arrange and snap icons to grid in folders other than the desktop?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management, user-interface

Is it possible to arrange icons in other folders the same way desktop icons can be arranged? Like arbitrarily placing the icons in different parts of the screen and also making them snap to grid.

[image]

PS.
I found a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/836555/windows-folder-organized-similarly-than-desktop) but it's for Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried the Window 7 answer to see if it works for Windows 10?

Comment: there's a note saying not to try it with other Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Individual folders were able to remember arbitrary icon order & position in (IIRC) `XP`. The information was stored with the folder's view settings in the registry (`HHKCU\...\Bags`). But, as the Windows Shell team explained to other MVPs & me at a summit, that feature was implemented before they imagined the magnitude of files & folders the average user would accumulate ( I think it was there since `3.1`  ). So the abilty was removed to improve response time & reduce registry bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Right-click on your desktop (not on an existing icon), move the mouse to View and made sure that "Auto arrange icons" is unchecked and "Align icons to grid" is checked. It should look like this:

[image: Right-click desktop view]

Comment: I'm asking how to do it in other folders, not the desktop.......

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. As Keith Miller says, it's not possible using Windows Explorer. You may be able to do it with another file manager.